# Module not found: Can't reslove 'firebase' in 'A:\react\react-app\src'

Tags: reactjs, firebase, redux, google-cloud-firestore

I have used React with firebase before. But I just ran into this error which I have never seen before.
I installed firebase with the command

```
npm i firebase
```

And I imported firebase with this import statement

```
import firebase from "firebase"
```

Then I got this error

Module not found: can't reslove 'firebase' in 'A:\react\react-app\src'

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The new [version](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/modular-upgrade#update_imports_to_v9_compat) of firebase change the way import works:

```
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app';
```

Or better, import the functionalities you need

```
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
```